# Adding a new row of data to a list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which has a row of summary statistics which changes from day to day, or week to week, depending on what information I put into various fields in the spreadsheet. I want to be able to write a VBA script that will copy this row of data onto another sheet, creating a new row of data, rather than replacing the previous entry. The purpose of this is to be able to make various time series graphs of the list as it changes in time. Does anyone know what lines of code I need to do this?

Comment: How about posting the basic data layout? It would be very tough to help without knowing what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code and it seems to apply to your situation,  rename Sheet1 and sheet2 appropriately.  Also, A1 needs to be the appropriate row or use "A" & Rows.Count

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _ 
Sheets("Sheet2"). Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

From: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131012162954AABezAL